# Why is fopen failing when in a file executed by a cron job?

Tags: php, cron, fopen

I have the following code in a PHP file:

```
if(!$fp = fopen(__DIR__ . '/up.lock', "c+"))
{
    die('Failed to open up.lock');
}
```

The purpose of the code is to prevent multiple instances of the file from running.

When I execute the file through the web browser **or** through shell, it works fine. However, when it is execute as a cron job, the message `Failed to open up.lock` is emailed to me.

Why isn't it working when executed as a cron job and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__DIR__` needs to be an absolute path. If it is, you have to make sure that your cron user have enough rights

Comment: "you have to make sure that your web browser have enough rights" doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: I thought `__DIR__` created an absolute path? Isn't that the point of using it? The PHP manual says it returns `The directory of the file`: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Comment: Absolutely right. I need some sleep. So check out the rights of the user who is launching the script. Could you show us your cron line and ls -al on the script ?

Comment: I just put `echo __DIR__;` into my cron and the correct path prints out, so the path in `fopen` is correct. I'm not sure what you mean by `ls -al `?

Comment: PHP doesnt succeed to open the file when the PHP script is launched from cron : if your path is OK it means the problem should be about the file permissions ; `ls -l` will show the permission of the lock file

Comment: If the first time you created the file, you did it from your web browser, the file could be owned by your webserver user ; in this case if you execute the script again via the cron, with a simple user, you wont be able the write in the file, which is a permission needed for a "c+" fopen

Comment: Yep, that's it. I just reached that conclusion myself. Thanks!